# Swagger - property name convention

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

In the past when I designed APIs , for both 2.0 and 3.0 version, I used camel case convention for property names. This time I could have the necessity of use  embedded underscore and capital letter for property name. Is this allowed by openapi? Can I use mix mode?

I searched for naming convention of property name but I' havent found.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know any valid string is allowed. Quoting and escaping is possible to create a valid string.

all this works:

```yaml
  foo-bar:
    type: string
  foo_bar:
    type: string
  'foo-bar':
    type: string
  'foo_bar':
    type: string
  "foo_bar":
    type: string
  "foo bar":
    type: string
  foo bar:
    type: string
  "foo: bar":
    type: string
```

Comment: Also uppercase string?